# Browsers do not recognize blur/focus in this code block

Tags: jquery, focus, blur

The items used in this code are loaded via AJAX. That is why I am using `live()`.

But blur/focus are not recognized. `Click()` is but not blur/focus.

I am using FF.

**The code:**

```
$(".card_signup_form input").live('focus', function(){
  $(this).css("color","#666666");
  $old_value = $(this).attr("value");
  $(this).attr("value", "");
  })
.live('blur', function(){
  if ($(this).attr("value") == "" ) {
      alert($old_value);
  };
});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? http://api.jquery.com/live/ lists the Caveats for the different versions.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Prior to 1.4.1, the live() method didn't accept focus() or blur() as arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. You should probably be using .val() to get the values of the inputs
2. It might be a better idea to store the old value as data in the DOM. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Have you tried looking at the debug console in Firefox to see if your code is throwing any errors? Hit Ctrl+Shift+J to bring it up.